# gcc branch prediction

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, branch-prediction

Here's my demo program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int cmp(const void *d1, const void *d2)
{
    int a, b;

    a = *(int const *) d1;
    b = *(int const *) d2;

    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    else if (a == b)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int seed = time(NULL);
    srandom(seed);

    int i, n, max = 32768, a[max];

    for (n=0; n < max; n++) {

        int r = random() % 256;
        a[n] = r;

    }

    qsort(a, max, sizeof(int), cmp);

    clock_t beg = clock();

    long long int sum = 0;

    for (i=0; i < 20000; i++) 
    {
        for (n=0; n < max; n++) {
            if (a[n] >= 128)
                sum += a[n];
        }
    }

    clock_t end = clock();

    double sec = (end - beg) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("sec: %f\n", sec);
    printf("sum: %lld\n", sum);

    return 0;
}



unsorted
sec: 5.000000
sum: 63043880000

sorted
sec: 1.000000
sum: 62925420000
```

Here's an assembly diff of two versions of the program, one with `qsort` and one without:

```
--- unsorted.s  
+++ sorted.s    
@@ -58,7 +58,7 @@
    shrl    $4, %eax
    sall    $4, %eax
    subl    %eax, %esp
-   leal    4(%esp), %eax
+   leal    16(%esp), %eax
    addl    $15, %eax
    shrl    $4, %eax
    sall    $4, %eax
@@ -83,6 +83,13 @@
    movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    -24(%ebp), %eax
    jl  .L7
+   movl    -24(%ebp), %eax
+   movl    $cmp, 12(%esp)
+   movl    $4, 8(%esp)
+   movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
+   movl    -32(%ebp), %eax
+   movl    %eax, (%esp)
+   call    qsort
    movl    $0, -48(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -44(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
```

As far as I understand the assembly output, the sorted version just has more code due to passing values to `qsort`, but I don't see any branching optimization/prediction/whatever thing. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Branch-prediction is done by the CPU, not by the compiler.

Comment: Isn't this a `C` duplicate of [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: no. That question asks why processing a sorted array is faster than an unsorted array, and the answer is branch prediction. This question asks how come that none of the branch prediction can be seen in assembly.

Comment: Note: `double sec = (end - beg) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` is computed in integer values only; you'll have to find a way to cast it to float.

Comment: @wildplasser, yeah missed that...

Comment: you are changing the seed each run, you cannot compare the time for one run to the next until you fix the seed and make the test repeatable.  Verify with a fixed seed you get the same dataset every run, add a loop to take the checksum.   Your printout already shows that you are comparing apples to oranges, the sum has to be the same to compare one run to the next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Branch prediction is not something you will see at the assembly code level; it is done by the CPU itself.

Comment: The compiler may emit a static branch prediction hint (`0x3e`) if the code is profiled optimized for the Prescott. But it didn't have any measurable performance benefits back then, that's why all newer processors ignore that branch hint silently.

Answer (score 0):

> #### [Built-in Function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html): long `__builtin_expect (long exp, long c)`
>
> You may use `__builtin_expect` to provide the compiler with branch prediction information. ***In general, you should prefer to use actual
>   profile feedback for this (`-fprofile-arcs`)***, as programmers are
>   notoriously bad at predicting how their programs actually perform.
>   However, there are applications in which this data is hard to collect.
>
> The return value is the value of `exp`, which should be an *integral expression*. The semantics of the built-in are that it is expected that
>   `exp == c`. For example:
>
> ```
> if (__builtin_expect (x, 0))
>   foo ();
> ```
>
> indicates that we do not expect to call `foo`, since we expect `x` to be *zero*. Since you are limited to *integral expressions* for `exp`, you
>   should use constructions such as
>
> ```
> if (__builtin_expect (ptr != NULL, 1))
>   foo (*ptr);
> ```
>
> when testing *pointer* or *floating-point* values.

#### ***Otherwise the branch prediction is determined by the processor...***

> [Branch prediction](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf#G3.1116080) predicts the branch target and enables the
>   processor to begin executing instructions long before the branch true
>   execution path is known. All branches utilize the branch prediction
>   unit (BPU) for prediction. This unit predicts the target address not
>   only based on the EIP of the branch but also based on the execution
>   path through which execution reached this EIP. The BPU can
>   efficiently predict the following branch types:
>
> • Conditional branches.
>
> • Direct calls and jumps.
>
> • Indirect calls and jumps.
>
> • Returns.

---

> [The microarchitecture tries to overcome this problem by feeding the most probable branch into the pipeline and execut[ing] it speculatively.](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A30%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C785%2C0%5D)

#### *[...Using various methods of branch prediction](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A30%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C296%2C0%5D).*